# Access97: INSERT INTO fails without a table or a query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to execute a simple `INSERT INTO` query on an old Access97 database.
I'm starting with a very short example - which doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO [MY-TABLE]( [Field1] ) 
VALUES ( "blabla" )
```

MY-TABLE is the actual name of the table and Field1 is a `String` field.
I get the error:

> Query input must contain at least one table or query

Because I need to insert literal value, I don't want to use a query here (i.e. a `SELECT FROM`)
Reading also the docs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861(v=office.12).aspx) I don't see where my SQL is wrong.

### UPDATE

Here a couple of screen shot of the *actual* table and fields:

[image]

here the SQL code:

[image]

Anyway...

## SOLVED!!

It works even with double quotes.
The problem was the push button I was using to check: using the "View" button leads to the error above. Instead **I must use the "exclamation mark"**.

Comment: Not quite sure is it the problem source or not - but try to replace surrounding double quotes `"` with single quotes `'`.

Comment: Bear in mind the docs you're reading are for Office 2007, ten years on from the version you're using. You may want to double-check with the actual Help file that comes with Access 97; given that the product's nearly 20 years old Microsoft have long removed that version of the documentation from the web. Can we see the *actual* SQL you're trying to run, with real table and field names? Alternatively, can you reproduce the problem for sure with the names you're using? (It may even be that VALUES wasn't an option in 1997! There are graduate programmers younger than your version of Access!)

Comment: The solution was... anticlimactic. :)

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to your own question and accept it. It will help more people in the future that way.  (And yes, for statements that don't have a result set to view, you need the "execute" action—exclamation mark—rather than "view", as there's nothing to view.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to *execute* the query using the "exlamation mark" button instead of the *view* one. This is because my query has not a result set to view - hence the error I saw.

By the way I confirm the syntax is accepted both with single or double quotes.